# Assigning variables inside an if clause

Tags: bash, zsh

I've got the following if clause:

```
if $(echo "$INDEX" | grep -c '^?? ' &> /dev/null) > 0 ;
```

It outputs count of strings matching grep expression. How can I assign that count to a variable inside an if clause, so that I don't have to execute that command twice to get count of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the result of a (series of) command to a variable like this:

```
matchedCount=$(echo "$INDEX" | grep -c '^?? ' &> /dev/null)
```

and then call it when it's needed like this: `$matchedCount`

Comment: Yep, sorry, my question was pretty dumb

Answer (score 0):

There are no operators to both assign and test at the same time in `zsh` like there are in some languages, but you don't have to run the operation twice. Instead of testing on the full command, test on an already assigned variable, then if your test comes back true you have the variable ready to go. If not you haven't wasted any cycles.

```
index_count=$(echo "$INDEX" | grep -c '^?? ' &> /dev/null)
if (( index_count > 0 )); then
    # Do your thing with $index_count
fi
```

Comment: Updated the `if` statement -- proper syntax for the arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an assignment inside an arithmetic expression and use the result in a test. This works in ksh, bash and zsh.

```
if ((n = $(echo "$INDEX" | grep -c '^?? ' &> /dev/null))); then
  echo "\$n is not zero"
fi
```

However, for the sanity of people reading your code (including you in three months), I don't recommend including assignments in a test that way. As others advise, assign to a variable first, then test the result of the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, reliably. Assign first, then test.